# Updating EF model throws ""Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I an create a new record with no issues, but whenever I update the model, even when the date isn't being changed, I get the "**Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime**" error.

I have confirmed that the dates in the existing db record to be updated are valid.

The below code snippet, will fail even though no date field is being updated.

```
var dbModule = db.Modules.FirstOrDefault(v => v.ModuleId == module.ModuleId);

dbModule.Name = module.Name;
//dbModule.Password = module.Password;
//dbModule.Colour = module.Colour;
//dbModule.Modified = module.Modified;

db.SaveChanges();
```

If I look at the trace, I see the command below, so am certain that no date fields are being updated.

```
ADO.NET:Execute NonQuery "update [dbo].[Modules]
set [Name] = @0
where ([ModuleId] = @1)"
```

For clarity, the operating environment is:

- ASP.NET MVC 3
- .NET 4.5
- SQL Server 2012 (Express)
- Models generated by database first approach, with corresponding edmx.
- DateTime model fields are of type DateTime in SQL Server

I have tried to use SQL Server Profiler, but it does't output the update statement to see the exact SQL, so am relying on the intellitrace provided above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Aughhhhh!  After days and days.

Using SQL Server Profiler, I found that I had to log both

- RPC:Completed
- SQL:BatchCompleted

That showed all the SQL statements, which allowed me to track it down to the fact that I had a trigger firing on the database, setting the Modified field, and using an incorrectly formatted string date.

Comment: Many years later, and your pain saves me from my own.  I hate triggers.  Or at least trigger abuse.  The ultimate in hidden gotchas.

Comment: That's fantastic!  I'm glad it spared you some agony.

Answer (score 0):

BlinkyBill, check if the datetime field on your entity/db is nullable, and if you are using the correct mapping. 
Also, you could try to explicity set this field on your update method.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried making the datetime field nullable, to no avail.